# Get rid of overlapping bounding boxes for contours in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am processing contours and creating a blob if two contours are within certain tolerance but the problem i am seeing is the overlapping of these contours, how can i have just one single bounding box without overlapping it? here is my code:

```
def get_contour_info(contour):
    contour_info = {}
    contour_info['x'], contour_info['y'], contour_info['w'], contour_info['h'] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    contour_info['cx'] = contour_info['x'] + contour_info['w'] / 2 
    contour_info['cy'] = contour_info['y'] + contour_info['h'] / 2 
    return contour_info

def process_contour(frame, contours):
    targets = []
    for c in contours:
        target_info = get_contour_info(c)
        target_info['cnt'] = c
        targets.append(target_info)

    full_targets = []
    for i, b in enumerate(targets[:]):
        matched = False
        for i2, b2 in enumerate(targets[i+1:]):
            if abs(b['cx'] - b2['cx']) < 50 and abs(b['cy'] - b2['cy']) < 50 :
                matched = True
                new_blob = np.concatenate([b['cnt'], b2['cnt']])
                hull = cv2.convexHull(new_blob)
                new_blob = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, 0.01*cv2.arcLength(hull, True), True)
                target_info = get_contour_info(new_blob)
                target_info['cnt'] = new_blob
                full_targets.append(target_info)
                targets.remove(targets[i])              
                break
        if not matched:
            full_targets.append(b)  

    contours = []    
    for g in full_targets:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(g['cnt']) 
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [g['cnt']], -1, (0,0,0), 1, lineType=8)
        contours.append(g['cnt'])
```

in Main function, some image processing goes here, after which i get contours from final_frame

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ....
    ....    
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(final_frame, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    process_contour(final_frame, contours)
```

This results is the below image:

[image: problem_image]

How can i get rid of the overlapping rectangles? and create one single bounding rect or perhaps two, three, four whatever bounding boxes that don't collide with each other?

Technically, this is what i am trying to acheive :

1) I read the contour and put that in a list and keep adding new contours to list

2) Compare c1 and c2 and see if they are within certain tolerance level, if yes, then i combine them, and remove the c1 from list and add the new blob to final_targets, if not, then i simply add c1 to the final_targets

but it seems, somewhere i am actually duplicating the addition, which is why they are overlapping.
Appreciate the response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's Not applicable as it's finding contours heirarchy level(very common for such issues) to eliminate the overlapping issue of an image but in my case we are past that stage.